# Ofstream doesnt work after I tried opening it with an UTF-16- string (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, file, utf-16, ofstream

My program opens a *.txt in an `std::basic_ofstream<char16_t>` and writes UTF-16 characters in it. 
Opening a file with ASCII characters as name works flawlessly.

The problem I face is the following:
Sometimes, the name of the file (given by the program, by design) contains non- ASCII characters. Since I can't open a file named with UTF-16 characters (because that would require a deep understanding of the topic, afaik), I try to filter that name out.
I do that by first opening the file with the `std::basic_ofstream<char16_t>`, look if it didn't work, and then open it with a "default" name, which consists only of ASCII characters.

Unfortunately, since the filestream is the same, I can't open the file with the default name anymore after I tried to open it with the ASCII- characters.

Here's a minimal code which illustrates my problem.

```cpp
#include "vector"
#include "cstring"
#include "string.h"
#include "sstream"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"

#include "locale.h" // Unicode
#include "codecvt"  // Unicode

typedef std::basic_string<char16_t> u16string;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::basic_ofstream<char16_t> outputStream;
    std::locale loc(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>);

    outputStream.imbue(loc);

    u16string currentPath = utf8_to_utf16("C:\\OutputDir\\");
    u16string endPath;

    u16string defaultName = utf8_to_utf16("Default");
    u16string customName = utf8_to_utf16("Jörg");       // Could be anything, e.g. Jörg, Bernard, Sean

    endPath += currentPath;             // Add path
    endPath += utf8_to_utf16("/");      
    endPath += customName;              // Add name
    endPath += utf8_to_utf16(".txt");   // File extension

    // Try to open file
    outputStream.open(utf16_to_utf8(endPath), std::ios::out);

    if(outputStream.good() && outputStream.is_open())
    {
        // Was able to open (because no utf16 chars were in the name)
        outputStream << utf8_to_utf16("This wörked.");
        outputStream.close();
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Wasnt able to open etc, so the name contains non- ascii characters. Need to open with default name.
        endPath.clear();
        endPath += currentPath;             // Add path
        endPath += utf8_to_utf16("/");      
        endPath += defaultName;             // Add default name
        endPath += utf8_to_utf16(".txt");   // File extension

        outputStream.open(utf16_to_utf8(endPath), std::ios::out); // This doesnt work... Why?

        if(outputStream.good() && outputStream.is_open())
        {
            // Was able to open (because no utf16 chars were in the name)
            outputStream << utf8_to_utf16("This wörked.");
            outputStream.close();
        }  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So basically it's like this:
Name contains no utf16 chars -> Everything works fine.
Name contains utf16 chars -> Doesnt open. Okay, alright. Then now please open with the default name, which does not contain utf16 chars -> wont do it.

If I open the file with an ASCII name in the first place, everything's okay.
But when I try to open with utf16 chars first (so it deliberately fails, because I want to sort out utf16 names) and then try to open with the default, it wouldn't work.

I hope you can understand my problem. Basically, I want to filter UTF-16 names and I do that by checking whether the file was opened successfully or not.

Can anyone help me? Or maybe someone has a more elegant solution. I'm open to it.

---

Btw dont mind the `utf16_to_utf8()` and `utf8_to_utf16()` functions. They do work perfectly fine and are not the problem. If you want some source code one them, heres my Qt misuse:

```cpp
std::basic_string<char16_t> MainWindow::utf8_to_utf16(std::string string)
{
    return QString::fromStdString(string).toStdU16String();
}
```

```
std::string utf16_to_utf8(std::basic_string<char16_t> string)
{
    return QString::fromStdU16String(string).toStdString();
}
```

Maybe there's a little error in them but as far as I use them they do work fine.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but please note that header files that you `#include` with double quotes are first search for in the same directory as the source file. For system header files (like all you include) you should use angle brackets, as in `#include <iostream>`. Will save you a few milliseconds of build-time for each header file you're including.

Comment: Thank you! I use Qt and actually dont know why I used "" instead of brackets, but I'll try to do that.

Comment: "Sometimes, the name of the file (given by the program, by design) contains non- ASCII characters" - Well, then you have to open it using those non-ascii characters. "I can't open a file named with UTF-16 characters (because that would require deep understanding of the topic, afaik)" - I'm afraid you just have to gain that "deep understanding of the topic" then. There are not always shortcuts to avoid learning stuff.

Comment: I wanted that to be my last option. But if it's like you say, then there'll be no shortcut...

Comment: @Jesper Juhl - the file is an output stream, so it's being created with the given name, I think?

Comment: @Sunburst Why do you append "/" to your endPath when currentPath already has a trailing backslash?

Comment: I think you need to call `outputStream.clear()` before your second attempt at reopening it; otherwise, the 'bad bit' flag will still be set, and maybe this will prevent the `.open()` call from succeeding? The standard says that `.open(…)` calls `.clear()` on success but I'm not sure if it will succeed if `.good()` is already flagged as false.

Alternatively, use a second `std::basic_ofstream` variable.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl - My mistake! I use the 'answer' box to create/format text (easier than in comments) … I meant to post it as a comment but had a brain-seizure (Sundays).

Comment: @Adrian I append it because I failed to make a good example. In my real code, its not there of course.

Comment: @Adrian I actually call *.clear() when I failed to open the file. Im sorry it didnt came out like that in my example. I already thought of a second `std::basic_ofstream` variable but since it has to be called quite often I dont want to create thousand variables. But thank you for your effort! I can reflect on my code again, now.

Comment: The whole approach seems very broken. Failure to open a stream does not mean there are non-ASCII characters in its name. Success does not mean there are no non-ASCII characters in its name. If the stream was opened successfully, there may or may not be any relationship between the file name as seen by the OS and the string used to open it, because your OS does not support UTF-8 file names and may interpret non-ASCII charaters you send to it in various non-obvious ways. If you want Unicode file names, use an API designed for it. If not, don't use Unicode strings as file names.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah I know its broken and I should have thought of another solution. Actually, I have. But this problem is not the only problem I have. The core problem is (as far as I can extract it), that I cant reopen a filestream after it failed to open. Its useless after using it once, somehow.

Comment: "I cant reopen a filestream after it failed to open". Why would you ever want this? Write a function. The stream object is local to the function. Open, manipulate, return. Anyway, if this is your core problem, create a [mcve] that focuses on it, without all this Unicode mismanagement around.

Comment: Yeah I thought it would be clearer if I show it in context to my problem, but it seems it wasnt. Ill try your method. Thank you!